# Confusing and unexpected behaviour of "if" statement in C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I have found this code in a collection of buggy code examples (http://matthieu-moy.fr/c/c_collection/) which i studied to sharpen my programming skills. You can see the code, how i executed it and the output below, as well as some experimenting i have done.

Can anyone explain this strange phenomena?

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int function_returning_false() {return FALSE;}

int main() {
    if (function_returning_false) {
        printf("function returned true\n");
    }
}
```

## Build

```
$ gcc Bug_Example_7.c -o Bug_Example_7_gcc
```

## Execution

```
$ ./Bug_Example_7_gcc
```

## Output

```
function returned true
```

## Conclusion

One could assume that the 'if' condition would not be true and therefore, the program would not print out anything. But apperently, one is wrong. I have compiled this code with gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), clang (10.0.0-4ubuntu1) and an online c compiler(https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), all with the same result: the printout "function returned true".

Further experimenting revealed that:

Replacing "FALSE" with "TRUE" (see code snippet below), build it, execute it, will result in the same printout ("function returned true"). Undoing the change and again build it and execute it doesn't change the output, no matter if the application file is deleted inbetween builds or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int function_returning_false() {return TRUE;}

int main() {
  if (function_returning_false) {
    printf("function returned true\n");
  }
}
```

Including the `stdbool`-library and replacing the defines "FALSE" and "TRUE" with "false" and "true" doesn't make a difference (see code snippet below).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int function_returning_false() {return false;}

int main() {
  if (function_returning_false) {
    printf("function returned true\n");
  }
}
```

Replacing the function "function_returning_false()" in the "if" statement with the boolean value "false" (see code snippet below), build it, execute it, the application will have no printout, as expected. But if the change is undone immediately afterwards and the code is built and executed again, the application will henceforth work as it should. The described phenomena will reappear after the application is deleted and the machine on which it was built is rebooted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int function_returning_false() {return false;}

int main() {
  if (false) {
    printf("function returned true\n");
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I ran the first code example and got no output: https://onlinegdb.com/3voiWmQLQ

Comment: Could not reproduce with `gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)` are you definitely recompiling and running the correct files?

Comment: What is the question here? I compiled your code with both VC (`cl`) and GCC in Windows. Neither printed anything. Closing because this does not seem to be a question but rather a blog post of some sort.

Comment: Ahah! Getting the code directly from http://matthieu-moy.fr/c/c_collection/bool_function.c does reproduce the issue

Comment: Note: that code is missing the parens: `if (function_returning_false) {` So it is not calling the function.

Comment: @SamBob... the link you posted **does not** call the function

Comment: I strongly believe your first experiment is not valid due to the experimenter's error.

Comment: I'm confused whether there is a question here. The original failing code from  matthieu-moy.fr/c/c_collection/bool_function.c  is from an intentional list of code gotcha's, and fails as intended.

Comment: Well, that code is different from the posted one. VTC non-reproducible.

Comment: Yet another perfect example why the question should contain an exact 1:1 copy of the program that causes the issue. Not some retyped thing only losely related to the real code. Showing incorrect code is just a complete waste of time for everybode involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't copy the program correctly. This is the real program that reproduces the bug:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int function_returning_false() {return FALSE;}

int main() {
  if (function_returning_false) {         // note, no ()
    printf("function returned true\n");
  }
}
```

So, it's not calling the function - it is passing the function as an argument to `if` and in boolean context, a function will always be `true`.